# React not re-rending DOM after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue re-rendering the DOM after a state change, Here is the code for the component:

```
<ul>
    { this.state.musicLibraryItems }
</ul>
```

I have a filter function that takes in a value from a text input and and filters the `musicLibraryItems` based on if the title has the value from the text input, I am doing that in the following function:

```
filterMusicLibrary(value) {
    let musicLibraryItems = [];
    this.state.musicGet.map(music => {
        if(music.title.includes(value)) {
            console.log(music.title)
            musicLibraryItems.push(
                <MusicLibraryItem key= {music.id} music={music} history={this.props.history}/>
            );
        }

    });
    console.log(musicLibraryItems, this.state.musicLibraryItems)

    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            musicLibraryItems: musicLibraryItems
            })
        }
    })

}
```

I think the problem is that I am not changing the reference to the state variable so it isn't realizing that the state has been changed. I was wondering what the best way to mutate the state variable so that the values in the `musicLibraryItems` is put into `this.state.musicLibraryItems` so that it can be rendered on the page.

Comment: What does `console.log(musicLibraryItems, this.state.musicLibraryItems)` show?

Comment: It's not clear whether or not this is causing your problem, but your state should only ever contain serializable data, not rendered components themselves. See [What Shouldn't Go in State](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html)

Comment: `musicLibraryItems` has the correct information based on the value of the text field, and `this.state.musicLibraryItems` has the non-filtered information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try

```
<ul>
  { this.filterMusicLibrary() }
</ul>
```

and change the filter to not change the state

```
filterMusicLibrary() {
    let musicLibraryItems = [];
    this.state.musicGet.map(music => {
        if(music.title.includes(this.state.title)) {
            console.log(music.title);
            musicLibraryItems.push(
                <MusicLibraryItem key= {music.id} music={music} history={this.props.history}/>
            );
        }

    });
    console.log(musicLibraryItems, this.state.musicLibraryItems);
    return musicLibraryItems;
}
```

You shouldn't store jsx elements on your state. If you are concerned about re-calculation of the list, try [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect)

Comment: I made some edits that made it work for me! Thanks @Murilo

Answer (score 1):

More like what @Murilo already mentioned, for filters you wouldnt want to add them to state, is more calculated state...just added a working sample

```js
const MusicLibraryItem = ({music}) => {
return <li>{music.title}</li>
}


const lotMusic = [{title: 'Awesome', id: '12121'}, {title: 'Kitchen', id: '121'},
                  {title: 'Golden', id: '21'}, {title: 'Beach', id: '121'}];
class App extends React.Component{

 constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {musicGet: lotMusic,filterValue: ''} 
   this.updateFilter = this.updateFilter.bind(this);
 }
 
 updateFilter(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
      
 }
 
  filterMusicLibrary(value) {
    let musicLibraryItems = [];
    this.state.musicGet.map(music => {
        if(music.title.includes(value)) {
            console.log(music.title)
            musicLibraryItems.push(
                <MusicLibraryItem key= {music.id} music={music} history={this.props.history}/>
            );
        }

    });
    
    return musicLibraryItems;
   }

   render(){
  
   
      return (
      <div>
      <h2>Test </h2>
      
      <input type="text" onChange={this.updateFilter} 
        name="filterValue"
        value={this.state.filterValue}/>
      
      <ul>{this.filterMusicLibrary(this.state.filterValue)}</ul>
      </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>




<div id="app">
</div>
```